# Is there a way to limit IAM access from within EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

First and foremost, I am aware of IAM roles and know that they would provide this feature. However, I have a requirement for a key attached to a IAM user.

Is there a way to limit access to resources from *within* EC2 instances (only allow if the origin of the request matches ec2 instances).

For example:

- Using credentials from developer's laptop: denied
- Using credentials from EC2 instance: allowed

We want to make sure that if these keys ever get leaked for whatever reason, no one will be able to control resources from outside our AWS environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but the level of granularity you want may result in more IAM management than you desire.  It's possible to add conditions to IAM statements that [restrict based on IP address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-deny-source-ip-address), so you can create a statement like the one below that lists the IPs of your instances:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "*",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {"NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": [
      "192.0.2.0/24",
      "203.0.113.0/24"
    ]}}
  }
}
```

However unless you use Elastic IPs for all your instances then their IPs can change over time, so you'd need some way of keeping these IAM statements properly updated.

Comment: Yeah I saw that example and fiddled with it but to no avail. I took keys from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition    See section: Available Keys for Conditions